# using struct as key in map

Tags: c++, c++11

i am using a map with key as 'tm structure' defined in time.h now when i'm using 
statement  `it=HashTime.find(tm structure object);` where it is the iterator then i am getting error like:

> no match for `'operator='` in `'((const CTime*)this)->CTime::HashTime.std::map<_Key, _Tp,     _Compare, _Alloc>::find [with _Key = tm, _Tp = long int, _Compare = CTime::compare, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const tm, long int> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const tm, long int> >, key_type = tm](((const std::map<tm, long int, CTime::compare>::key_type&)((const std::map<tm, long int, CTime::compare>::key_type*)m_ntmDate))) = m_datesec'`

Comment: what's the type of `it` and `HashTime`? and does it work if you use `auto it = HashTime.find(...);`?

Comment: can you post a minimal example?

Comment: Actually i am a bit new to c++ so this what i have coded

Comment: Actually i am a bit new to c++ so this what i have coded

Comment: map<struct tm,time_t> HashTime;
map<struct tm,time_t>::iterator it;
time_t          m_datesec;

Comment: and i'm using it in a function like this:

Comment: time_t MakeTime( struct tm &trf)
{
        it =HashTime.find(trf);
        if( it   == HashTime.end())
        {     struct tm tmTemp = trf;
              m_datesec= mktime (&tmTemp);
              HashTime[trf]= m_datesec;

        }
        else
        {
              return HashTime.find(trf) ;
        }

Comment: i've tried to do operator overloading for

Comment: 1.bool operator =(struct tm &D)                                   2. bool operator()(struct tm &A,struct tm &B)
{ if ((A.tm_mday < B.tm_mday) && (A.tm_mon< B.tm_mon)&&   (A.tm_year < B.tm_year) &&  (A.tm_hour< B.tm_hour)&&   (A.tm_min< B.tm_min) &&  (A.tm_sec< B.tm_sec))   return true else return false;}   3.bool operator==(struct tm& rhs)
{ if ((trf.tm_mday == rhs.tm_mday) && (trf.tm_mon == rhs.tm_mon)&&   (trf.tm_year == rhs.tm_year) &&  (trf.tm_hour== rhs.tm_hour)&&   (trf.tm_min== rhs.tm_min) &&  (trf.tm_sec== rhs.tm_sec))
 return true;
 else
 return false;
}

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add your code?

Comment: 1.bool operator =(struct tm &D)
2. bool operator()(struct tm &A,struct tm &B) { if ((A.tm_mday < B.tm_mday) && (A.tm_mon< B.tm_mon)&& (A.tm_year < B.tm_year) && (A.tm_hour< B.tm_hour)&& (A.tm_min< B.tm_min) && (A.tm_sec< B.tm_sec)) return true else return false;}
3.bool operator==(struct tm& rhs) { if ((trf.tm_mday == rhs.tm_mday) && (trf.tm_mon == rhs.tm_mon)&& (trf.tm_year == rhs.tm_year) && (trf.tm_hour== rhs.tm_hour)&& (trf.tm_min== rhs.tm_min) && (trf.tm_sec== rhs.tm_sec)) return true; else return false; }

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish, you can convert between ```struct tm``` and ```time_t``` using ```mktime```, ```gmtime``` and ```localtime```.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct valueInfo
{ 
  int value1; 
  int value2; 
  int value3; 

  valueInfo(const int A,const int B,const int C) : 
    value1(A),value2(B),value3(C) {}
};

class valueComp 
{
public:

  bool operator()(const valueInfo& A,
          const valueInfo& B)
    const
    { return A.value2<B.value2; }
};

typedef std::map<valueInfo,double,valueComp> MapCTYPE;

int
main()
{
  MapCTYPE TMap;

  valueInfo B(1,2,3);
  valueInfo C(3,3,4);

  TMap.insert(MapCTYPE::value_type(B,4.5));
  TMap.insert(MapCTYPE::value_type(C,8.4));

  MapCTYPE::iterator vc=TMap.find(MapCTYPE::key_type(1,2,8));
  if (vc!=TMap.end())
    {
      std::cout<<"Success:"<<vc->second<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot :) your post has solved my operator overloading errors.This is what the i have written :  void MakeTime( struct tm &trf)
{      it =HashTime.find(trf);
       if( it   == HashTime.end())
        {  m_datesec= mktime (&trf);
           HashTime[trf]= m_datesec;
        }
        else
        {  HashTime.find(trf) ;
        }
}
private:
       map<struct tm,long int,valueComp> HashTime;
       map<struct tm,long int,valueComp>::iterator it;
       long int          m_datesec;
};
but i am getting error:no matching function for call to'Time::MakeTime(tm*)

Comment: and i am calling the MakeTime function in other header file with   strptime (strDate.c_str (), strFormat.c_str (), &m_tmDate);
    struct tm trf= m_tmDate;
    cobj.MakeTime(&trf); where m_tmDate is another tm structure   having some values set for each of its variable.

Comment: valueComp is the class  with bool operator()(const tm &A,const tm &B) const  and cobj is object of Time class..